# Backbone.js, Rest API and anonymous session

Tags: javascript, rest, session, backbone.js, cookies

I've got a backbone webapp, It consists into several form pages w/o any authentication.
All users are anonymous but i need a kind of logic to identifying them along the process.

Actually this is a comparator service.

I consume thru CORS a API in charge to deliver some contents, such as querying a Vehicule database, things related to a insurance policy and geo location...

No issues regarding consuming datas.

Now the question is more regarding how to save the anonymous users datas thru a multi-step form in the API.

The Goal would be, each time a user click on the next step, anonymous user datas will be save ( this is for analytics reasons ) and secure a bit the API with these POST requests.

As the webapp is in pure JS, i was thinking to do something like this :

1. if a cookie doesn't exist, i generate on the client side a session_id with with a js crypto lib and store this session_id into a new cookie ( with a expiration ) . Then a backbone model ( Session/Singleton ) will be in charge to store this session_id into a redis-cache store thru a Backbone.save().  Expiration of the Redis Key will match expiration of the cookie. Id attribute of the Session Model will be the session_id.
2. If the cookie exist. i'll fetch() the session from the API thru a getSession verb.

In this way i could keep tracking of every anonymous users to save the datas in my API. Do you think this is a good pattern or too naïve ?

Now, about securing the API... i'm stuck.

I was thinking about HMAC but if the secret key is stored on the client side ( backbone app ), shared for all users, someone could inspect the js client code, even uglyfied, and find the key...

I read many docs about this, but all are talking about a username/pwd/token scheme, in my case i've got only anonymous users...

Maybe, in the REST paradigm, anonymous users means that the datas are not sensitive.. .

Any advices ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Anything that is stored client side is not secure. When it comes to an SPA, you usually authenticate a user using a username and password. Once the user is authenticated, you send a an Authorization token in the header of every request. If I am understanding your question correctly, you are worried about sensitive data being sent and inspected when the user is registering? If that is the case, you are best using a secure connection. I am curious to know how you think this is different for a non-backbone or SPA app? You would still be sending the data over HTTP, REST or non REST.